# Remove part from string in java

Tags: java

Guys i have that string `page-116.jpg` and i want it to be `page.jpg`
my trail is

```
text.replaceAll("^[\\-|\\d]+", "")
```

but it doesn't  give me the desired output ... any help ??

Comment: What do you think the `^` means?

Comment: What do you think your entire regex means? What makes you think so?

Answer (score 0):

You could use `-\\d+` will match `-numbers`.

```
text = text.replaceAll("-\\d+", "");
```